# WinError 10053 en script con Python y PyTS3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet

He hecho un pequeño script con Python y el módulo PyTS3 para mutear desde mi cliente automáticamente a todos los usuarios conectados en un servidor de TeamSpeak3 que no tenga agregados a mi lista de amigos.

Se conecta al cliente a través de un complemento llamado ClientQuery, que trae Team Speak por defecto. 
*(ClientQuery: offers a local telnet interface on port 25639 to remotely control the TeamSpeak 3 client).*

Mi código es:

```
import ts3
import os
import sqlite3

#apikey
apikey = open("API-Key.txt", "r").read()

def TS3_Muter():

    #import friendlist
    friendlist = []

    with sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/" + str(os.getenv("username")) + "/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/settings.db") as database:
        cursor = database.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Contacts;")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            row = str(row)
            nickname = row[(row.find("Nickname=") + 9):row.find("\\nFriend")]
            code = int(row[(row.find("\\nFriend=") + 9): row.find("\\nAutomute")])
            if code == 0:
                friendlist.append(nickname)

    #ts3
    with ts3.query.TS3ClientConnection("localhost") as connection:
        connection.exec_("auth", apikey=apikey)
        connection.exec_("use")
        for client in connection.exec_("clientlist"):
            if client["client_nickname"] not in friendlist:
                connection.exec_("clientmute", clid=client["clid"])
            else:
                connection.exec_("clientunmute", clid=client["clid"])
        connection.exec_("quit")


while 1:
        TS3_Muter()
```

El script en sí me funciona perfectamente, pero pasados los primeros 1-3 minutos de ejecución, acaba crasheando con el siguiente mensaje en la consola:

**ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexi�n establecida por el software en su equipo host
[Finished in 77.165s]**

He probado a ejecutarlo desactivando previamente el firewall, pero el problema persiste.

¿Alguien sabría por qué salta este error, o cómo solucionarlo? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error no depende de tu script python. Es el error general que aparece cuando intentas escribir en un socket que ha sido cerrado desde el otro lado.

Podría deberse a que existe una conexión de larga duración con el cliente TS3, que éste decide cerrar en un momento dado, pero no parece el caso en tu código. Si no me equivoco, la función `TS3_Muter()`, dentro de su segundo bloque `with`, establece una conexión con el cliente, se autentica, obtiene la lista de clientes, ejecuta un "mute" o "unmute" sobre cada uno de ellos, y después abandona con el comando "quit". Además, al salirse del bloque  `with`, el socket por el que estaba conectado será automáticamente cerrado, por lo que no parece que se mantenga una conexión abierta mucho tiempo.

Sospecho más bien que pueda tratase de una protección del propio cliente ante lo que toma como un *ataque DoS*, puesto que tu programa principal simplemente llama a `TS3_Muter()` en un bucle infinito sin darle un respiro.

Añade un `time.sleep(1)` por ejemplo en el bucle principal, que espacie las peticiones 1 segundo. No sólo darás un descanso al cliente, sino también a tu CPU, pues tener un **bucle infinito de polling sin pausas** no es muy recomendable.

Por otro lado, a menos que la base de datos de amigos esté cambiando muy frecuentemente, podrías optimizar el acceso a la misma, haciendo que por ejemplo la base de datos se consulte sólo una vez cada N accesos al cliente TS3. Por ejemplo, con N=60 la base de datos se consultaría una vez por minuto (suponiendo que espacias las llamadas al cliente 1 segundo como recomendé antes).

## Implementación alternativa

Aquí te muestro otra forma de implementarlo que:

- Usa una sola conexión y la recicla
- No satura al cliente, espaciando los comandos 1 segundo
- Sólo consulta la base de datos de amigos cada minuto

Es ésta:

```
import ts3
import os
import sqlite3

#apikey
apikey = open("API-Key.txt", "r").read()

def get_friendlist():
    #import friendlist
    friendlist = []

    with sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/" + str(os.getenv("username")) + "/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/settings.db") as database:
        cursor = database.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Contacts;")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            row = str(row)
            nickname = row[(row.find("Nickname=") + 9):row.find("\\nFriend")]
            code = int(row[(row.find("\\nFriend=") + 9): row.find("\\nAutomute")])
            if code == 0:
                friendlist.append(nickname)

def mute_not_friends(connection, friendlist):
    for client in connection.exec_("clientlist"):
        if client["client_nickname"] not in friendlist:
            connection.exec_("clientmute", clid=client["clid"])
        else:
            connection.exec_("clientunmute", clid=client["clid"])

def TS3_Muter():
    counter = 0
    N = 60
    with ts3.query.TS3ClientConnection("localhost") as connection:
        connection.exec_("auth", apikey=apikey)
        connection.exec_("use")
        while True:                            # Infinite loop
            if counter % N == 0:
                friendlist = get_friendlist()
            mute_not_friends(connection, friendlist)
            time.sleep(1)
            counter += 1

TS3_Muter()
```

**Disclaimer** :-) No he podido probar el código anterior porque no tengo el resto del software. En concreto tengo duda de si el comando '"use"' que se le envía al cliente basta hacerlo una sola vez, como es el caso en mi código.

Comment: Supongo que es lo que comentas de que el cliente interpreta un determinado número de conexiones seguidas en un corto espacio de tiempo como un ataque. Con un time.sleep(1), aguanta mayor rato que antes, pero vuelve a acabar crasheando. Por ello, quizás sea mejor conectarme una sola vez, y mantener viva la conexión de alguna manera mientras la necesite. Voy a mirarme la documentación de PyTS3 a ver si hay alguna forma de hacerlo.

Comment: También es posible que la parte del cliente que admite conexiones telnet contenga algún bug, pues quizás no sea una situación normal el estar recibiendo muchas conexiones. A lo mejor cada conexión que recibe crea algún recurso que luego no es liberado. Pasado un cierto número de conexiones comienza a dar problemas. En cualquier caso, mantener una única conexión parece mucho más razonable.

Comment: @psy He actualizado la respuesta, prueba este código a ver

Comment: Lo he conseguido solucionar combinando tu ejemplo de arriba con un método que trae el módulo para mantener viva la conexión: `send_keepalive()`. ¡Todo va genial! :)